# how to change the color of buttons?

Tags: material-design, material-ui

I read the docs and I was able to change the color of others but cannot get it to change the color of label in the buttons. So far this is my code:

```
 const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
    datePicker: {
    calendarYearBackgroundColor: lightBlue800,
    calendarTextColor: "white",
    selectColor: lightBlue800,
    color: lightBlue800
}})
```

[image: a sample]

Answer (score 0):

Try using timePicker

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
    timePicker: {
    calendarYearBackgroundColor: lightBlue800,
    calendarTextColor: "white",
    selectColor: lightBlue800,
    color: lightBlue800
}})
```

I still wasn't able to change the button text color in mine. I'm assuming it's because I have the `flatButton` color set independently. So be careful of that as well.